# Detect Google Chrome Aura with JavaScript, possible?

Tags: google-chrome

```
navigator.userAgent
```

does not report it:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1613.1 Safari/537.36"

I only see it (Aura) literally in chrome://version/strings.js, which gets reported in chrome://version/